# Is an alamofire request to a HTTPS domain any different from that to HTTP?

Tags: ios, swift, django, alamofire

I just added SSL to my backend framework (Django REST API) and I want my iOS application to talk to it. Do I have to do anything differently on the iOS side of my project? How do I tell Alamofire to encrypt the data its sending? Or Does it happen automatically?

Comment: Assuming you use the `https` protocol, nothing else should be required, as long as the SSL certificate is valid (https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/116)

Comment: @ColinBasnett Thanks! Since I am really new to this, I don't fully understand it... Here's what was written on Heroku "With Automated Certificate Management (ACM), Heroku automatically manages TLS certificates for all apps that have Hobby and Professional dynos on the Common Runtime. Certificates handled by ACM automatically renew before they expire, and new certificates are created automatically whenever you add or remove a custom domain. All applications with paid dynos include ACM for free." I just upgraded to Hobby; Does this mean I have a valid certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference is using https instead of http. I have the same setup at work, and originally thought I was going to have to delve into certificates. I started heading in that direction and then realized all my requests worked as soon as I stuck the "s" on the end.

I will say, while using NSStream, you do have to setup the stream to handle the certificate. I am doing this in another application, but that is below the URLRequest class. I am unsure of how low level Alomofire actually delves, but it will definitely handle everything you desire without doing anything differently.

Comment: Will it automatically encrypt the data or send it as plain text?

Answer (score 0):

Just update URLs inside your app to use "https" and you are done.